# How to show progress of sql server SP on winform client?

Tags: winforms

we have winforms client application that calls .net web services which further calls sql server SP . on one particular occasion, we are calling sp which does heavy batch processing on the server. is there any way we can update progress back on the winform client while sql server sp is running ? 
I thought of calling my main webmethod asynchronously which does all batch processing. and then call another webmethod in separate thread which periodically queries server to know progress. is this possible ? or is there any other approach to achieve this? 
please advice.

thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using a method similar to what you suggest.  The stored procedure updates a status table as it runs, and the other thread queries that status table with the NOLOCK hint.  The interesting thing I found in doing it this way is that, if the work is happening in a transaction, and the transaction gets rolled back, the status bar will even run backwards as it rolls back!  However, large amounts of work should probably not be done in a single transaction for performance reasons.